# Attempt to move a large virtualbox vdi file repeatedly fails from one drive to another

Tags: virtualbox, rsync, vdi

I have read numerous ways of moving a large file from one drive to another, but none of them address the issue I am having.This could be a post for a VirtualBox forum and I will post there as well and share the answer that works with the other forum.

I am using System 76 Bono Extreme laptop which is now about 9 years old. The hardware is still in very good shape. It has 32 Gigs of Ram, and three storage drives. One is 400 Gb SSD, one is a 750 Gig, 7200 RPM HDD, and one is a 1TB 5400 rpm HDD.

I recently decided to do a new install of Ubuntu 20.10, because I wanted to encrypt my HD. I stored most things on an external 4 Tb HDD to restore back to my HD after it was encrypted with the new Ubuntu system, but was not having any luck moving my VB vdi file to the external HDD. Repeatedly the transfer would fail at 92.3 Gigs. The vdi I am trying to transfer is 232.9 Gigs.

I have now encrypted the SDD and 1st HDD. I wanted to have my vdi on the 3rd drive because of its storage capacity. But to do that I have to move it to the 2nd drive temporarily while I encrypt the 1 TB drive then move it back. I have read about the issues of moving from large files to an external hdd, but I am now having an issue moving from a local hdd.

Today I thought I would try rsync to make the transfer and the below message came up and the transfer failed. This time instead of having a smaller file size of 92.3 Gb, nothing was transferred.

The following is the output of lspci.

*

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM
> Controller (rev 09) 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200
> v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) 00:01.1 PCI
> bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI
> Express Root Port (rev 09) 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7
> Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
> 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216
> Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04) 00:1a.0 USB controller:
> Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host
> Controller #2 (rev 04) 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7
> Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI
> Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) 00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7
> Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
> 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
> Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel
> Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
> #1 (rev 04) 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04) 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7
> Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
> 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus
> Controller (rev 04) 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA
> Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 670MX] (rev a1) 01:00.1 Audio device:
> NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1) 04:00.0
> Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI
> Express Card Reader (rev 01) 04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek
> Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
> Controller (rev 0a) 05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation
> Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)

- 

I have tried to compress the file prior to transfer, but that has failed as well.

I should mention my vdi got that big due the work I do and it has grown. But with the work I do, most of it is stored on my host public folder which is recognized by my virtual Windows machine as network storage, so I do not know why the vdi grew so large considering all of my work is store, as far as Windows is concerned, on a network drive.

Any guidance regarding what direction to look is much appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I seriously doubt the process for moving a large file on Ubuntu 20.04 would be any different. If you do not know the answer to the question, maybe it would be best to not say anything at all. For example, you could have said, "We do not support 20.10, but this is how it is done on 20.04..." So imagine I asked for help with 20.04 and answer that question.